# Can I count row of a table " $("this tbody tr").length?

Tags: jquery, this, each

I have 3 tables with same class name `table-sort`. I would like to access those table by `.each()` and count the `tr` inside the `tbody`.

is it `$("this tbody tr").length`?

```
$('.table-sort').each(function(index) {
   var rowCount = $("this tbody tr").length; //not work , Could you please correct this?

   var rowCount1 = $(this).find('tbody > tr').length; //this is working fine
   alert(rowCount + '-' + rowCount1);
})
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the code

```
$('.table-sort').each(function(index) {
   var rowCount = $("tbody tr", this).length; //will work now..

   var rowCount1 = $(this).find('tbody > tr').length; //this is working fine
   alert(rowCount + '-' + rowCount1);
})
```

But the second code you use, *which works*, should be enough ..

---

You could also use the [inherent table properties of the table DOM object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6156016)

```
$('.table-sort').each(function(index) {
       var rowCount = this.rows.length;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Gaby, Its amazing, quick answer.